# How to deploy Solana private chain with at least 4 nodes for testing on single or multiple machines

Tags: testing, deploy, testnet

I want to send transactions to the blockchain and obtain the execution results of the transactions.I followed the instructions in the official documentation below for the setup, but I'm not sure if this meets my requirements.
https://docs.solana.com/cluster/bench-tps

```
git clone https://github.com/solana-labs/solana.git
cd solana
TAG=$(git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1))
git checkout $TAG
cargo build --release
NDEBUG=1 ./multinode-demo/setup.sh
NDEBUG=1 nohup ./multinode-demo/faucet.sh > faucet.out 2>&1 &
NDEBUG=1 nohup ./multinode-demo/bootstrap-validator.sh > bootstrap.out 2>&1 &
NDEBUG=1 nohup ./multinode-demo/validator-x.sh > validator.out 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Hello. Could you be more specific with your question please. This is indeed the recommended method to spin up a multinode test cluster. Did you get any errors when you tried it out?

Comment: @Ademola Hello.Thanks for your reply.I want to deploy some programs on the private chain (like smart contracts in Ethereum), call them, and obtain the corresponding results. However, after completing the steps above, I don't know what the next steps are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to set up a local Solana cluster on your machine to send transactions and obtain the execution results. The instructions you followed are correct and should meet your requirements.

To send transactions to the blockchain and obtain the execution results, you can use the Solana CLI tools. Here's a step-by-step guide:

1. **Install the Solana CLI tools** by following the instructions at https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools.
2. Once you have the CLI tools installed, you can **create a new keypair** for your transactions by running:

```
solana-keygen new
```

This will generate a new keypair and save it to the default location.

3. Next, you can **send a transaction** to the blockchain by running:

```
solana transfer <AMOUNT> <RECIPIENT_ADDRESS> --from <YOUR_KEYPAIR> --url http://localhost:8899
```

Replace `<AMOUNT>` with the amount of SOL you want to send, `<RECIPIENT_ADDRESS>` with the recipient's address, and `<YOUR_KEYPAIR>` with the path to your keypair file.

4. To **obtain the execution results** of the transaction, you can run:

```
solana confirm <TX_SIGNATURE> --url http://localhost:8899
```

Replace `<TX_SIGNATURE>` with the transaction signature you received after sending the transaction.

By following these steps, you should be able to send transactions to your local Solana cluster and obtain the execution results.

Comment: Thank you very much! This has indeed inspired me on how to interact with the deployed private chain. I will take a closer look and study it carefully! Thanks again for your response!